# is there a way (workaround) to create an object of type `T` in a generic class?

Tags: typescript

Like in the question is there a way or workaround to create an object of type `T` within a generic class?

```
type Foo = { /*...*/ };

class Bar <
  T extends Foo  
> {
  public readonly foo: T;

  public constructor(
    init?: { foo: T } | undefined
  ) {
    this.foo = init?.foo ?? new T(); // ERROR: 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)
  }
};
```

Comment: If you want to write `new xxx()` you need an actual `xxx`. There's no "workaround" for that, unless I misunderstand what you're asking for.  If you need a constructor of `T` objects you need to pass one in, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NlXLxN), but that seems to defeat the purpose and instead you should just make `init` required and not optional like [this](//tsplay.dev/wRPz5m).   What is your use case?  I'm wondering if this is an XY problem where you only think you need a magical constructor from nowhere, so that we can give you an answer more useful than just "no this is impossible".

Comment: @jcalz you are right, this is a XY problem, but gladly the trick with passing constructor directly did solve a problem for me. I come from `c++`. In `C++`'s templates it is completely valid to write `new T()` in the way i expected above, without the need to pass the `ctor` directly. In few minutes i should write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

this did work for me.

```
// ---- . ---- ---- ---- ---- . ----
// Foo:
// ---- . ---- ---- ---- ---- . ----

type FooInit = {
  readonly prop01?: string | undefined;
};

type FooInterface =
  Required<FooInit>; // `FooInterface` is a part of my private idiom. Not to be mistaken with a popular naming convention `IFoo` or `TFoo`.

class Foo
  implements
    FooInterface
{
  public readonly prop01: string;

  public constructor(
    init?: FooInit | undefined
  ) {
    this.prop01 = init?.prop01 ?? "default prop01";
  }
};

// ---- . ---- ---- ---- ---- . ----
// Bar:
// ---- . ---- ---- ---- ---- . ----

type BarInit <
  GenericFooInit extends FooInit
> = {
  readonly foo?: GenericFooInit | undefined
}

type BarInterface <
  GenericFoo extends Foo
> = {
  readonly foo: GenericFoo
}

class Bar <
  GenericFooInit extends FooInit,
  GenericFoo extends Foo
>
  implements
    BarInterface<GenericFoo>
{
  public readonly foo: GenericFoo;

  public constructor(
    GenericFooConstructor: new (
      init?: GenericFooInit | undefined
    ) => GenericFoo,
    init?: BarInit<GenericFooInit> | undefined
  ) {
    this.foo = new GenericFooConstructor(init?.foo);
  }

  // once again `make` is a part of my private idiom.
  public static readonly make = <
    GenericFooInit extends FooInit,
    GenericFoo extends Foo
  > (
    GenericFooConstructor: new (
      init?: GenericFooInit | undefined
    ) => GenericFoo,
    init?: BarInit<GenericFooInit> | undefined
  ): Bar <
    GenericFooInit,
    GenericFoo
  > =>
    new Bar <
      GenericFooInit,
      GenericFoo
    > (
        GenericFooConstructor,
        init
    )
};

// ---- . ---- ---- ---- ---- . ----
// Use case:
// ---- . ---- ---- ---- ---- . ----

type NeoFooInit = FooInit & {
  prop02?: string | undefined;
};

type NeoFooInterface =
  Required<NeoFooInit>

class NeoFoo
  extends
    Foo
  implements
    NeoFooInterface
{
  public readonly prop02: string;

  public constructor(
    init?: NeoFooInit | undefined
  ) {
    super(init);
    this.prop02 = init?.prop02 ?? "default prop02";
  };
};

const bar01 = Bar.make <NeoFooInit, NeoFoo> (NeoFoo);

const bar02 = Bar.make <NeoFooInit, NeoFoo> (NeoFoo, {});

const bar03 = Bar.make <NeoFooInit, NeoFoo> (NeoFoo, {
  foo: {}
});

const bar04 = Bar.make <NeoFooInit, NeoFoo> (NeoFoo, {
  foo: {
    prop01: "prop01"
  }
});

const bar05 = Bar.make <NeoFooInit, NeoFoo> (NeoFoo, {
  foo: {
    prop02: "prop02"
  }
});

const bar06 = Bar.make <NeoFooInit, NeoFoo> (NeoFoo, {
  foo: {
    prop01: "prop01",
    prop02: "prop02"
  }
});

const bar07 = Bar.make <NeoFooInit, NeoFoo> (NeoFoo, {
  foo: {
    prop01: "prop01",
    prop02: "prop02",
    prop03: "prop03" // Rightfully reports error:
                     // Type '{ prop01: string; prop02: string; prop03: string; }' is not assignable to type 'NeoFooInit'. 
                     //   Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'prop03' does not exist in type 'NeoFooInit'. Did you mean to write 'prop01'?. ts(2322)
  }
});
```